# How to set dynamic value in tree parameter?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

As we know, there is a button "Add an item" in tree view of form view, click button "Add an item" to create a new line of the one2many.

As we know, there is a field "state" in many models.

---

**So, I try to fix that match the following two requirements:**

1) when state is not "done", I can see "Add an item" and edit other lines.

2) when state is "done", "Add an item" is disappear and edit other lines.

---

I have tried a lot but failed.

Such as:

1)

```
<tree create="0" edit="1">
```

It's not dynamic, so it does't match any requirements.

2)

```
<tree create="[('state','!=','done')]" edit="1">
```

Does not take effect and gives an error.

Error message:
  "Unknown CORS error"
  "An unknown CORS error occured. The error probably originates from a 
   JavaScript file served from a different origin. (Opening your browser 
   console might give you a hint on the error.)
  "

3)

```
<tree create="state!='done'" edit="1">
```

Error is the same with above.

4)

```
<tree attrs="{'create':[('state','!=','done')]}" edit="1">
```

No effect or error.

Comment: Tree view consists of many records,so if one record is in done state, the add an item button should disappear for you?

Comment: @Navi very very thanks! I made a low-level mistake！
That I replace the attrs in another module.

Comment: ok @star all the best

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is almost right, but you are putting those attributes in wrong tag. You are trying to make a field readonly, which field is in that case in `tree` form inside a `form` view. So all you have to do is set readonly condition in the `field` tag, the `One2many` for which the tree representation is added. So the code will be like:

```
<field name="one2many_field_name" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'done')]}">
    <tree editable="bottom">
    .....
    .....
    </tree>
</field>
```

Also to be noted, you can set readonly condition to the `field` definition itself in the `Model` definition, in that case you don't have to define readonly condition in every view you are using that field in.

Comment: thank you very much!  I also want to edit some lines when "parent.state" is "done". It's solved by add "parent." before "state" in the "attrs". I was so stupid yesterday, made low-level mistakes！

Answer (score 0):

```
<field>
    <tree attrs="{'create':[('parent.state','!=','done')]}">

    </tree>
</field>
```

I made low-level mistakes！

That I replace the attrs in another module, and the "state" should be "parent.state".